# check if nextflow channel is empty

Tags: channel, nextflow

I am trying to figure out how to check if a channel is empty or not.

For instance, I have two processes. The first process runs only if a combination of parameters/flags are set and if so, checks also if its input file from another process (input via a channel) is not empty, then it creates a new input file for a second process (to eventually replace the default one). As a simplified example:

```
.....
.....

// create the channel here to force nextflow to wait for the first process
_chNewInputForProcessTwo = Channel.create()

process processOne {
  when:
    params.conditionOne && parameters.conditionTwo
  input:
      file inputFile from _channelUpstreamProcess
 output:
      file("my.output.file") into _chNewInputForProcessTwo
  script:
    """
    # check if we need to produce new input for second process (i.e., input file not empty)
    if [ -s ${inputFIle} ]
      then
          <super_command_to_generate_new_fancy_input_for_second_process> > "my.output.file" 
      else
          echo "No need to create new input"
    fi
   """
}

// and here I would like to check if new input was generated or leave the "default" one
_chInputProcessTwo = Channel.from(_chNewInputForProcessTwo).ifEmpty(Channel.value(params.defaultInputProcessTwo))

process secondProcess {
  input:
      file inputFile from _chInputProcessTwo
......
......
etc.
```

When I try running with this approach it fails because the channel `_chNewInputForProcessTwo` contains `DataflowQueue(queue=[])` therefore, not being actually empty.

I've tried several things looking at the documentation and the threads on google groups and on gitter. trying to set it to empty, but then it complains i am trying to use the channel twice. putting `create().close()`, etc.

Is there a clean/reasonable way to do this? I could do it using a value channel and have the first process output some string on the `stdout` to be picked up and checked by the second process, but that seems pretty dirty to me.

Any suggestions/feedback is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Marius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to avoid trying to check if the channel is empty. If your channel *could* be empty and you need a default value in your channel, you can use the [ifEmpty](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#ifempty) operator to supply one. Note that a single value is implicitly a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel). I think all you need is:

```
myDefaultInputFile = file(params.defaultInputProcessTwo)

chInputProcessTwo = chNewInputForProcessTwo.ifEmpty(myDefaultInputFile)
```

Also, calling `Channel.create()` is usually unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Steve! You are right. It worked. I had to add `Channel.create()` because, for some reason, NextFlow was not queuing/creating the DAG correctly. I still do not know why. But I've cleaned the working tree and removed everything that was cached and now it works correctly. For the sake of "completeness" and "cleanness", in my case I now use this one-liner: `file inputFileProcessTwo from _chNewInputForProcessTwo.ifEmpty(params.defaultInputProcessTwo)` Maybe the syntax difference is due to the version (19.09.0-edge). Thanks again for the tips!